# smooth out the abrupt `top` property change

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

```
$('#navbr').affix({
 offset: {
    top: $('headdiv').height()
 }
});
```

How do I make the top change smooth?

Currently, when I move close to the `headdiv`, a sudden change can be seen. How do I make the transition process smooth?

Answer (score 0):

add css to your #navbr

```
 #navbr * {
 -webkit-transition:all 1s cubic-bezier(0, 0.59, 0.24, 1.33);
 -moz-transition:all 1s cubic-bezier(0, 0.59, 0.24, 1.33);
 -o-transition:all 1s cubic-bezier(0, 0.59, 0.24, 1.33);
 transition:all 1s cubic-bezier(0, 0.59, 0.24, 1.33); 
  }
```

or any other transition option

Comment: it did not work :/ I do not want this code to heppen suddenly top: $('headdiv').height().I want to do it slow by setting 1,2,3,4 till it reaches height or any other method.

Comment: Try to add height as 'constant' if U can-> headHeight = $('headdiv').height(); and use it in offset: { top: headHeight }.  can U send a code for this as I cann't find any other solution for this